# .mp3 and .wav files works on simulator, but not on device

Tags: objective-c, ios4, audio, avplayer

I have very common question as i searched for it but cant get the correct answer for me.

here is the piece of code on which I m trying hard to play Audio files.

in viewDidLoad method:

```
    NSURL *buttonSound = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/button4.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSURL *correctSound = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/key_drop1.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSURL *wrongSound = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/sound8.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];


    NSError *error;

    ButtonPressedSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:buttonSound error:&error];
    ButtonPressedSound.numberOfLoops = 0;


    correctAnsweredSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:correctSound error:&error];
    correctAnsweredSound.numberOfLoops = 0;


    wrongAnsweredSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:wrongSound error:&error];
    wrongAnsweredSound.numberOfLoops = 0;
```

in IBAction of pressing a button m calling "play" in this way.

```
                [ButtonPressedSound play];

            [self performSelector:@selector(stop) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.50];

                [correctAnsweredSound play];

                [self performSelector:@selector(stop) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.50];

                [wrongAnsweredSound play];

                [self performSelector:@selector(stop) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

my play and stop methods are :

```
-(IBAction)play
{

self.ButtonPressedSound.currentTime = 0;
[self.ButtonPressedSound play];

self.correctAnsweredSound.currentTime = 0;
[self.correctAnsweredSound play];

self.wrongAnsweredSound.currentTime = 0;
[self.wrongAnsweredSound play];


}

-(IBAction)stop
{
[self.ButtonPressedSound stop];
[self.correctAnsweredSound stop];
[self.wrongAnsweredSound stop];

}
```

what I have done so far...

I have searched to these links but not get the answer for my code.

[AVAudioPlayer only plays in simulator but not device why?! (iPhone-SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016618/avaudioplayer-only-plays-in-simulator-but-not-device-why-iphone-sdk)

[mp3 Sounds Playing on simulator but not on Device (Audio BeatBox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657832/mp3-sounds-playing-on-simulator-but-not-on-device-audio-beatbox)

http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/04/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-part-4-basic-game-audio/

...........

I have checked all the names n there is not any typo mistake.

Dont know where m getting wrong , pls help !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had similar problems before, but this solution is just a random guess that worked for me at the time.

On the real iPhone, file paths are case-sensitive.  On the simulator, they are not.  So I would check to make sure your file paths are exactly correct, including case.